# Php Mysql Multiple Group By Results in Single Line

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have data structure Below
[image]

I need results with group by country and group by count results like below
[image]

I have tried below code it is

```
$sql = "SELECT Country, 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   ip_ptc WHERE type='view' and ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']) .") as view,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   ip_ptc WHERE type='interactions' and ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']) .") as interactions,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   ip_ptc WHERE type='click' and ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']) .") as click,
        ROUND(100.0*COUNT(ip)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_ptc WHERE ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']) ."), 2) as percentage
    FROM ip_ptc 
    WHERE ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']) . 
    
   " GROUP BY Country
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Total Clicks' ip, COUNT(ip) as sum,COUNT(ip) as sum,COUNT(ip) as sum,'100.00'
    
    FROM ip_ptc
    WHERE ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']);
```

it is showing same count results for views,interactions and clicks like below.

[image]

I know this is because country is not passed in count statement but getting no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation here along with `ROLLUP`:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(Country, 'Total Clicks') AS Country,
    SUM(type = 'view') AS views,
    SUM(type = 'interactions') AS interactions,
    SUM(type = 'click') AS clicks
FROM ip_ptc
WHERE
    ad_id = ?
GROUP BY
    Country WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: @roy Try removing the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Removing WITH ROLLUP keyword from Group By Country working like a charm thanks